# How can I make vertical output instead of horizontal output?

Tags: r, output-formatting

I am trying to make the horizontal output from a particular function into a vertical output and I am trying to figure out with the "cat" function but could not find the way to do so. The function that I am concerned is the following:

```
 context <- function (a,b,c)
 {
 U=matrix(0, nrow = c, ncol = c)
 t = 0.4
 m = 0.2
 for (i in 1:c)
 { 
 U[i] = t*a + b/i - 0.224
 }
 cat(U)
 }
 context(2,3,7)
```

The output that I get is like:

```
 3.576 2.076 1.576 1.326 1.176 1.076 1.004571 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

However, I do not know I to make this output in the vertical way by manipulating the function itself.
I would greatly appreciate if I could get help on this.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Why don't you have the function return `U` instead of using `cat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you create all those zeros.

Maybe you'd like to return a matrix?

```
context <- function (a,b,c)
{
  t = 0.4
  m = 0.2
  U = t*a + b/seq_len(c) - 0.224
  as.matrix(U)
}

context(2,3,7)

#         [,1]
#[1,] 3.576000
#[2,] 2.076000
#[3,] 1.576000
#[4,] 1.326000
#[5,] 1.176000
#[6,] 1.076000
#[7,] 1.004571
```

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly I needed to do! I did not know I needed the "as.matrix" formula for this! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`t(data)` might be a better solution.

For more details, please check: https://www.r-statistics.com/tag/transpose/ .